# "ImportError: DLL load failed" in PyCharm w/ conda: how to automatically import conda's PATH?

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I have installed python via conda, created a new environment, installed PyCharm and configured it to use this environment.

When I start a python console in PyCharm, I am greeted with a

> C:\Users\9973879\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\foo\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py:226: UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved

Indeed if I try to `import sqlite3`, I get a

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

However `Project Interpreters > Interpreter Paths` does list `C:\Users\9973879\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\foo\{DLLs, Lib, site-packages}`. Also, importing this package from a python interpreter launched from the command line — in that very same virtual environment — succeeds.

**EDIT**

It seems the problem comes from the `PATH` environment variable. When calling `conda activate foo`, `conda` adds a bunch of folders to the `PATH`, containing various libraries (in particular `sqlite3.dll`).

When pointing to an existing environment (or creating a new one), PyCharm does automatically add folders to the `PYTHONPATH` as pointed out before, but does not seem to add anything to the `PATH`.

I tested this assumption by running PyCharm from the command line after calling `conda activate foo`, and it works. Of course, having to launch PyCharm from a specific conda environment is not great as I am stuck with this specific environment.

How could PyCharm be configured to automatically update the environment as `conda activate` does? Shouldn't it do it straight out of the box?

Comment: I'd start by removing some PyCharm plugins. Do you actually use iphyton? If not, remove it. If yes, remove it temporarily to see if that solve the problem :)

Comment: @Robyc thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my question. Unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use? 2019.1 EAP contains a relevant fix (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234), EAP can be downloaded from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Comment: @PavelKarateev I thought this would be the same issue, but it turns out 2019.1 EPA does not solve my problem here.

Comment: Finally I found somebody with EXACTLY my issue, albeit many years previous.  Unfortunately, the answers here don't help ... I absolutely cannot hard-code the appropriate conda environment PATH into my overall system PATH (a brute-force measure that will work for the right-here-right-now for ONE particular project, but is not scalable), and I'm already running a much newer version of conda (4.10.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be solved by upgrading to the latest 4.6.7 version of conda. The relevant line from the [release notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#467-2019-02-21) *might* be

> - revert conda prepending to PATH in cli main file on windows (#8307)

I am not sure why it affected PyCharm and not plain python in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue by adding [DLL](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to my **< path_to_environment >/DLLs** location

Comment: Not the hero we deserve, but the hero we need.

Comment: Hi, @Hima could you please be more specific on how to the dll to the correct path in Pycharm. I was not able to figure it out. Cheers

Comment: @Xavier do you have a conda environment created and selected against your project in pycharm ? In this case you don't need to do anything in pycharm, Just go to actual location of Environment-> DLL and add DLL.